# webpack configuration just for css

Tags: css, webpack

I'm creating a small CSS library to use it in all my projects.

To make it easily accessible I set up a node project with a simple server that serves a static page with a showcase of the library.

Now, I would like to bundle all my .scss file in a single .css file, that way, in the project I'm gonna import the library in, I won't need to set up a sass-loader but I will be able to import directly the .css bundled file.

This is the structure of the project:

```
/
|_assets
|      |_ _aux.scss
|      |_ _mixins.scss
|      |_ _lib.scss
|
|_index.html
|_webpack.conf.js
|_main.js
```

Index.html is the simple showcase of the library, main.js is a webserver to serve index.html and webpack.conf.js is the following file:

```
  const CssEntryPlugin = require("css-entry-webpack-plugin");

  module.exports = {
      entry: {
          "styles": "assets/lib.scss"
      },
      output: {
          path: "assets",
          filename: "lib.css"
      },
      module: {
          rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.scss$/,
                  use: [{
                      loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                  }, {
                      loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                  }, {
                      loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                  }]
              }
          ]
      },
      plugins: [
          new CssEntryPlugin({
              output: {
                  filename: "lib.css"
              }
          })
      ]
  };
```

When I execute the command:

```
webpack webpack.conf.js
```

I get the following error:

```
No configuration file found and no entry configured via CLI option.
When using the CLI you need to provide at least two arguments: entry and output.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. did you try just running `webpack` instead of `webpack webpack.conf.js`? 2. your entry point is `assets/lib.scss` but this file is not in the tree-structure. Is the `_` handled by `sass-loader`?

Comment: @francoisromain I am sure, the underscore is just a graphical gimming to illustrate the tree.

Comment: @scipper no, it's a convention for [sass partials](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4).

Comment: Sorry guys I have changed the name because it was the name of the company I'm working for, but it's correct. The "_" it's a convention for partials and actually lib.scss doesn't have one. If I use "webpack" without any parameter I get the same error.

Comment: rename `webpack.conf.js` to `webpack.config.js`